# Avoid precision loss when marshalling time.Time objects

Tags: json, go, time, marshalling

I have made a [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Orjl8sKEqmn) reproducing my issue. I have some test that fail because the json Marshal method seems to lose precision during the conversion of a `time.Time` object.

Running the below code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "time"
)

type myStruct struct{
    Now time.Time `json:"time"`
}

func main() {
    expect := &myStruct{Now: time.Now()}
    
    fmt.Println(expect.Now.String())
    
    byteData, err := json.Marshal(expect)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    
    actual := &myStruct{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(byteData, &actual)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    
    fmt.Println(actual.Now.String())
}
```

Outputs:

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

The issue is that when I run any test involving the conversion of a `time.Time` object, I cannot use any standard method to compare the results (testify, reflect...).

Is there a way to either, preserve precision when marshalling a `time.Time` object, or 'round' the time value to a lower precision ?

Comment: That's not a loss of "precision". It's omitting the monotonic portion of the time object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `expect := &myStruct{Now: time.Now().Local()}` or
`expect := &myStruct{Now: time.Now().UTC()}`. This will remove your precision part and you can test it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

One can also use [Time.Round](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Round):

> Round returns t stripped of any monotonic clock reading but otherwise
> unchanged.

So:

```
time.Now().Round(0)
```

will strip away the monotonic offset leaving the rest of the time components intact (timezone etc.)